# Does JBoss7 allow Hibernate 3 xml configuration?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jboss

First I excuse if this is a stupid question.
I am trying to deploy my spring application into JBoss 7. Hibernate entities are configured with xml. That means PojoClass.hbm.xml and not annotated.

What I want know simply is, do JBoss 7 or 8 version support only Hibernate (version 3) mapping Annotations (POJO  class mappings to database tables)? and no xml configurations ? If it is possible, would you let me have any guidance resource URL please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check out [this guide](https://developer.jboss.org/en/jbossas/blog/2013/10/16/adding-a-hibernate-3-module-to-as-7) exampling how you can switch from Hibernate 4 to Hibernate 3.
2. Once you enable Hibernate 3, you only need to set the [JBoss Transaction Manager resolving settings](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v3.2/userguide/html/ch06s04.html).

Comment: Thank for your answer. Since the default Hibernate version is 4, I have to config to make it to version 3. Then,one more clarification please. Do you think that all features of Hibernate 3 are supported ? (Including Hibernate XML configurations.not annotations?)

Comment: With both Hibernate3 and Hibernate4 you can use both annotations and xml. [You can add HBM resources](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-programmatic) and Hibernate will use them so that you can simply rely on Hibernate API, without having to interact with anything from JPA.